# Почему Mapstruct отлично работает в методе main() , но не работает в сервлете

Tags: java, mapstruct

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

ошибка  -

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers

Подключаю maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <!-- due to problem in maven-compiler-plugin, for verbose mode add
                      showWarnings -->
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>
                                -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true
                            </arg>
                            <arg>
                                -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true
                            </arg>
                            <arg>
                                -Amapstruct.verbose=true
                            </arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Вызываю в servlet

```
    @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String description = req.getParameter( "description" );
            IncomingDto incomingDto = new IncomingDto(description);
            SimpleEntity simpleEntity = SimpleDtoMapper.INSTANCE.mapToSimple( incomingDto);
            SimpleEntity saved = service.save( simpleEntity );
            OutGoingDto map = SimpleDtoMapper.INSTANCE.mapToDTO( saved );
            // return our DTO, not necessary
        }
```

Получаю ошибку

```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapstruct/factory/Mappers
    org.example.servlet.mapper.SimpleDtoMapper.<clinit>(SimpleDtoMapper.java:12)
    org.example.servlet.SimpleServlet.doPost(SimpleServlet.java:43)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    org.example.servlet.mapper.SimpleDtoMapper.<clinit>(SimpleDtoMapper.java:12)
    org.example.servlet.SimpleServlet.doPost(SimpleServlet.java:43)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Если запускаю в main()

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger( Main.class.getName() );

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String description =  "description" ;
        IncomingDto incomingDto = new IncomingDto(description);
        SimpleEntity simpleEntity = SimpleDtoMapper.INSTANCE.mapToSimple( incomingDto);
        System.out.println(simpleEntity);

    }
}
```

То все отлично работает.

Comment: Наверно потому, что соответствующая библиотека не была включена в веб-архив (.war-файл) и/или корректно задеплоена в веб-приложении и контейнер сервлетов (томкат или что-то подобное) не может её обнаружить.

Comment: Напиши подробно, почему не работает и приведи полный стэк ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Проект не собирался в war ник.

В pom.xml отсутствовал плагин maven

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Добавил все заработало.